# Django/South "python manage.py migrate CaseReport" raises an exception

Tags: python, django, django-south

I'm attempting to add South support to an existing Django application.

What I've done:

```
pip install south
Add 'south' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Test that South is now there:
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08)
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import south
>>>

Also, check that South shows up in manage.py help:

python manage.py help

python manage.py syncdb

Make south manage your models:

python manage.py convert_to_south CaseReport

On other instances:
manage.py migrate app_name 0001 --fake

Make your model changes in models.py

Check what -would- happen (dry run):

python manage.py schemamigration CaseReport --auto --stdout

Run it for real:
python manage.py schemamigration CaseReport --auto

Finally:
python manage.py migrate CaseReport
...but this is tracebacking for me.  :(
```

The traceback I get is:

```
$ python manage.py migrate CaseReport
Running migrations for CaseReport:
 - Migrating forwards to 0002_auto__add_field_casereport_date_time_of_last_update.
 > CaseReport:0002_auto__add_field_casereport_date_time_of_last_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 254, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 329, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 111, in run
    if not south.db.db.has_ddl_transactions:
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 124, in has_ddl_transactions
    if getattr(connection.features, 'supports_transactions', True):
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.func.__name__] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 676, in supports_transactions
    self.connection.leave_transaction_management()
  File "/home/dstromberg/miniconda/envs/CaseReport/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 322, in leave_transaction_management
    "Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK")
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: Transaction managed block ended with pending COMMIT/ROLLBACK
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Django 1.6 with Miniconda CPython 2.7.5, South 0.8.4 and MySQL 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 on Linux Mint 16.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you worked with your DB beforehand and there's a pending transaction. Maybe try to restart your DB server. Also is there any part in your code where do you manually handle transactions management?

Comment: I restarted mysql with "sudo service mysql restart", but I still get the traceback when running "python manage.py migrate CaseReport".   Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: that's cool, but the second part of my comment is the more important: is there in your code any place where do you manually manage transactions?

Comment: I am not using transactions explicitly at this time.

Comment: how do these models look like?

Comment: I have "class CaseReport(models.Model)", with 2 CharField's, 3 DateTimeField's, 1 CharField choice, 2 TextField's and an IntegerField.  These are all class variables.  I've provided a __unicode__ method that converts most of these fields to unicode and u'/'.join()'s them.  It's pretty skeletal - the project hasn't seen production use yet.   However, I don't want to just delete my database and start over, because we want to use what I learn for South'ing a different project that Is in production.

Comment: I just tried "drop table ROLLBACK_TEST;", but it didn't help.

Comment: I just tried adding the DROP privilege to my Django database user, but it didn't help; same traceback.  I also tried grant all for my Django database user, and I still get the same traceback.

Comment: I just tried creating a mysql user corresponding to my Linux username, to see if South was perhaps ignoring the DATABASES setting in settings.py.  But it didn't help.

Comment: I've not said anything about AUTOCOMMIT in DATABASES.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and spent hours applying different solutions. The problem was there can be either no permissions for MySQL user to operate tables or presence of ROLLBACK_TEST table in database. I had both, so maybe it will help someone:

Grant user required permissions on database, then flush priveleges to take effect:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INDEX 
    ON `databasename`.* TO 'username'@'ip.address' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'ip.address';
```

Delete table ROLLBACK_TEST if any:

```
USE databasename
DROP TABLE ROLLBACK_TEST;
```

Then migration went smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was completely lost, I never thought to look for tables owned by a different user.